# My wordpress website is showing all the languages in the browser title bar instead of the selected one

Tags: wordpress, title

My website on wordpress is showing all the languages in the browser title bar instead of only one. like if am on the english version, it should display only english title in the browser title bar but its not the case as its displaying all translated languages

Answer (score 0):

First check what is your system language if it is English it should be show all the posts and content in English language.

if this thing is not useful use this plugin to switch the language and make it default English

http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-language-switcher/

Comment: i already have language switcher and it works..my problem is that on the browser's title bar all languages appear..for example i am on english language and i click on home page, it should only appear home on the browser title bar but in my case it appears in all languages.